# Quarkus native building using third party library

Tags: java, maven, native, quarkus, graalvm

I'm finding some issues trying to build a native executable using Quarkus native-image plugin on GRAALVM 23.0 JDK 17.
Shortly i'm implementing a jwt authentication in my Quarkus application using another alredy working library (also written by me) doing all the logic through io.jsonwebtoken dependecies (jjwt-impl, jjwt-api, jjwt-jackson). The native building process succeed without any errors or warning but when i run the executable it throws the exception:

`2024-02-05 14:52:33,296 INFO  [it.pnt.net.qua.han.ExceptionHandler] (executor-thread-1) Unable to load class named [io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder] from the thread context, current, or system/application ClassLoaders.  All heuristics have been exhausted.  Class could not be found.  Have you remembered to include the jjwt-impl.jar in your runtime classpath`

I've tried to register that class for reflection using the proper annotation, but the problem is that the error persits with another missing class. It seems that it doesn't bring all the mandatory dependency.

My question is about using an existing library, i know that i can use the quarkus library but if i'm working on existing projects it means to rewrite tons of code.

Comment: Could you post code with anotation, maybe you miss some classes.